# Camel - Receive reply from ReplyTo using either Producer/Consumer Template

Tags: apache-camel, queue, message-queue, producer-consumer, tibco-ems

Our app (say **abc**) need to interact with another app (say **xyz**) using Tibco queues.
The **xyz** will listen to incoming messages in Queue1.
Then it would send back the response message Temp queue, we have populated in the request message header.

From **abc**, we are sending the messages to Queue1 using ProducerTemplate.
We have set the JMSReplyTo in the headers.
Now we want to receive the message which would be sent to the Temp Queue.
Along with the body, we also need the headers which **xyz** would be populating and sending us.

Is this possible using Producer/Consumer Template? If yes, can you highlight that pls.
If not, what is alternative?